# find longest line between 2 bars without any in between bar intersection in amibroker

Tags: amibroker

I am looking AFL code WITHOUT using LOOPS to find longest line between 2 bars without any in between bar intersection. See picture links in comment below, it explains the problem clearly.

code for high to high and low to low.
In high to high shifting happens from right to left (future to past)
In low to low shifting happens from left to right (past to future)

Can this be done without loops?

Comment: https://ibb.co/vc4w5p1
https://ibb.co/GvHHhD9
https://ibb.co/tH0WcRM
https://ibb.co/cwsQfWt
https://ibb.co/93bBQGq
https://ibb.co/McJ1k1m

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.